# ListView to move up when there is insufficient height

Tags: flutter, listview, layout

I have `ListView` that has following layout:

[image]

When there is not enough space (smaller devices), I would like to have the list "scrolled", so all elements 2-5 are still visible, and only first one is visible only partially. Something like this:

[image]

I know this can be basically achieved by `ListView`. However, when there is enough space (big screens) I want all elements to be displayed and spread evenly (Element 1 touching the top, Element 5 touching the bottom). Can somebody help with this?

If I use basic `ListView`, elements are either centered on start, center or end, example (start):

[image]

I have tried using `SizedBox`, however that is not working, since the SizedBox has still the same size:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          SizedBox(...),
          Container(...),
          Container(...),
          Container(...),
          Container(...),
        ]
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

In other words, I need to achieve that the scroll is visible only when it is needed. Even, scrolling feature is not needed in this case, moving of Element 1 to the top (beyond screen) would be sufficient. Thank you for any help.

Comment: i guess here scrolling is impossible, but you can try with wrapping every widget with expanded and provide flex as per your requirement.

Comment: So just to clarify, do you want the items in the list to change its size? or just scroll to the 5th item?

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is too small, you can make the `Listview` start from the last item by defining a `ScrollController` and pass it to the listview, then initialise a `.JumpTo` command:

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });
  }
```

You could also use the listview parameter `reverse: true` which would also reverse the order of the list.

Now if the screen is too big and you want to adjust the sizes of the containers so that they cover the whole screen, you will have to use `ConstrainedBox` to have adjustable sizes.

```
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 50.0,
                  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / list.length,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: const Text('Element 1'),
                ),
              ),
```

In the above example, the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` is the measurement of the phone's device height. It is divided by the number of items in the list so that they can spread evenly. Or you can use expanded widget on every item to adjust the flex/aspect ratio between each.

If you have an appbar and want to exclude it from the height size, you can do so like this

```
final appBarHeight = AppBar().preferredSize.height;
final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final availableHeight = screenHeight - appBarHeight;
```

If your minHeight constraint happens to be so small that its not covering the whole screen, you can use a LayoutBuilder widget to expand the containers to fit the entire height of the screen.

```
   Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          double containerHeight = constraints.maxHeight / 4;
          List list = [
            Container(
              height: containerHeight + 70,
            ),
            Container(
              height: containerHeight - 20,
            ),
            Container(
              height: containerHeight - 10,
            ),
            Container(
              height: containerHeight + 50,
            ),
            Container(
              height: containerHeight + 10,
            ),
          ];
          return ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            children: [
              list[0],
              list[1],
              list[2],
              list[3],
              list[4],
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

You will have to calculate or play around with your height numbers to find the suitable balance

Comment: Nice answer. However, when I add `ConstrainedBox`es to the list, they increase the height of listview to the point that it is higher than screen (and when `minHeight` is set to 1.0, it does not use the whole height of the screen). Is it possible to use something like `Expanded` or `Flexible` elements, that maximize if there is place, and minimize if not?